# Properties of a module that is an internal direct sum

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, direct-sum

I know from a course I'm taking on algebra that the following is true:

Let $R$ be a ring, let $M$ be an $R$-module, and let $M_1, M_2 \le M$. If $M_1 + M_2 = M$ and $M_1 \cap M_2 = \{0\}$, then $M \cong M_1 \oplus M_2$.

My question is, does the converse also hold? That is, does $M \cong M_1 \oplus M_2$ imply that $M_1 + M_2 = M$ and $M_1 \cap M_2 = \{0\}$? If so, can somebody please provide a brief proof or an intuitive explanation of why it is true? I think I'm missing something here about internal direct sums, since in the textbook I'm reading whenever we have $M \cong M_1 \oplus M_2$, the author seems to conclude that $M_1 \cap M_2 = \{0\}$, but I've never seen a theorem or an exercise stating directly that we can make that assumption. Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Yes, this is true. Which condition are you having trouble checking?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'm having trouble checking both conditions.

Comment: Note that $M_1\simeq \{(m,0)\mid m\in M_1,0\in M_2\}\subseteq M_1\oplus M_2$. This will help greatly in checking both conditions. It is also how to interpret the statement $M_1\cup M_2$ when the two modules a priori have nothing in common.

Comment: Sorry Arthur, but can you elaborate a bit in how that will help me check both conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you mean that there is an isomorphism $\phi:M_1\oplus M_2\to M$ given by $\phi(m_1,m_2)=m_1+m_2$?

Well, $\phi$ is surjective, so we must have $M_1+M_2=\phi(M_1\oplus M_2)=M$. On the other hand, if $m\in M_1\cap M_2$, then $\phi(m,-m)=0$. Since $\phi$ is injective we must have $(m,-m)=(0,0)$, i.e. $m=0$. Hence, $M_1\cap M_2=(0)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, David. Everything you wrote down makes perfect sense to me. However, what if you just know that $M_1 \oplus M_2$ is isomorphic to $M$, but you don't necessarily know that the map you use in your answer is an isomorphism? If that is the case, can you still conclude that $M = M_1 + M_2$ and $M_1 \cup M_2 = \{0\}$?

Comment: @Gecko No. Consider the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $M=\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $M_1=M_2=\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus(0)\cong\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks a lot for your help.